# Downstream project in GitLab not able to access the artifacts from the upstream project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, artifacts

Upstream project .gitlab-ci.yml

---

```
image: node:10

stages:
    - build
    - build-child

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

project-build:
    stage: build
    only:
        - master
    script:
        - npm install
        - npm run build
    artifacts:
        expire_in: 90 days
        paths:
             - ./dist

trigger-child-build:
    stage: build-child
    trigger: 
        project: ghanshyamgehlot/childTestProject
        strategy: depend
```

Downstream project .gitlab-ci.yml

---

```
image: node:10

stages:
    - build-this-project
    
cache:
    paths:
        - ./node_modules/

build-this:
    stage: build-this-project
    needs:
        - project: ghanshyamgehlot/testProject
          job: project-build
          ref: master
          artifacts: true
    only:
        - master
    script:        
        - npm install
        - npm run build
```

As soon as the downstream project pipeline is triggered by the upstream project, the following error appears in the downstream project pipeline even though the artifact has been successfully created by the upstream project:

> This job depends on other jobs with expired/erased artifacts: